# POSIX partial write() and Signal Interrupts

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, posix

From the man page of `write()`

> Note that a successful write() may transfer fewer than count bytes.
>          Such partial writes can occur for various reasons; for example,
>          because there was insufficient space on the disk device to write all
>          of the requested bytes, or because a **blocked write() to a socket,
>          pipe, or similar was interrupted by a signal handler** after it had
>          transferred some, but before it had transferred all of the requested
>          bytes.  In the event of a partial write, the caller can make another
>          write() call to transfer the remaining bytes.  The subsequent call
>          will either transfer further bytes or may result in an error (e.g.,
>          if the disk is now full).

I have the following questions

1) In the case of `write()` being interrupted by signal handler after a partial transfer, will write() set the `errno` to `EINTR` ?

2) If `errno` is not set, is there a way to identify such an event with out extra piece of code (Like installing signal disposition and setting a flag value to `true`) ?

**Note :** The further `write()` calls are successful in transferring the remaining bytes after the event of signal interrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your individual numbered questions:

1. `errno` is only meaningful after one of the standard functions returns a value indicating an error - for `write`, -1 - and before any other standard function or application code that might clobber it is called. So no, if `write` returns a short write, `errno` will not be set to anything meaningful. If it's equal to `EINTR`, it just happens to be; this is not something meaningful you can interpret.
2. The way you identify such an event is by the return value being strictly less than the `nbytes` argument. This doesn't actually tell you the *cause* of the short write, so it could be something else like running out of space. If you need to know, you need to arrange for the signal handler to inform you. But in almost all cases you don't actually need to know.

Regarding the note, if `write` is returning the full `nbytes` after a signal arriving, the signal handler was *non-interrupting*. This is the default on Linux with any modern libc (glibc, musl, anything but libc5 basically), and it's almost always the right thing. If you actually want interrupting signals you have to install the signal handler with `sigaction` and the `SA_RESTART` flag clear. (And conversely if you're installing signal handlers you want to have the normal, reasonable, non-interrupting behavior, for portability you should use `sigaction` and set the `SA_RESTART` flag rather than using the legacy function `signal`).

Comment: So installing signal handler is a way to go. I can think of other alternatives like blocking the signal and using signalfd() along with select() to catch the signal interrupt event. In note, I meant to say further calls to write() were not producing errors. Thanks !

Comment: @MohithReddy: What are you actually trying to do? Your question is asking about what you can expect to see rather than what you want to achieve...

Comment: I feel like your answer to part 2 sidesteps the more general question here: "If `write` doesn't write any bytes, `errno` will give me a clue as to why it couldn't write them. If `write` writes some bytes but not all of them, is there a way of knowing why it couldn't write them all?"

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: No, there's not. But aside from interruption by a signal, which is messy and something you should avoid, most such conditions will be seen the next time you call `write` trying to finish the unfinished operation. Many like `EPIPE` are sticky, but some like `ENOSPC` may be transient and subject to TOCTOU issues.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try it and see:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void handle_sigalrm(int sig) {
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    act.sa_handler = handle_sigalrm;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);
    int fds[2];
    pipe(fds);
    int bufsize = fcntl(fds[1], F_GETPIPE_SZ) + 10;
    char *buf = calloc(bufsize, 1);
    ssize_t written;
    printf("will attempt to write %d bytes and EINTR is %d\n", bufsize, EINTR);
    alarm(1);
    errno = 0;
    written = write(fds[1], buf, bufsize);
    printf("write returned %td and errno is %d\n", written, errno);
    return 0;
}
```

That program makes a pipe that nothing will ever read from, does a write to it that's bigger than the kernel's buffer, and arranges for a signal handler to run while the write is blocking. On my system, it prints this:

```
will attempt to write 65546 bytes and EINTR is 4
write returned 65536 and errno is 0
```

Thus, the answer to "In the case of write() being interrupted by signal handler after a partial transfer, will write() set the errno to EINTR?" is "no, it won't".

Comment: Yes, got the same result! So an extra piece of code is required to identify such an event then. Thanks !